# FileUploadException not displying on Firefox 3.6.15

Tags: firefox, file-upload

I am uploading a very large file that exceeds the DiskFileUpload's max file size limit. I was expecting the FileUploadException to be thrown and displayed on the browser's page. However, on Firefox 3.6.15, the standard "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading" message. I know that the code was throwing the exception because I see the error msg in the log (where the code logs its stdout). 
On IE 8, 7, 6, and an earlier version of Firefox, the exception message was being displayed on the browser page.

Does anyone know of some parameter I can set or use on the server side (e.g., DiskFileUplod, FileUpload) that would allow the error to get through to the client for display? Or is this some known issue with this version of Firefox? Any insight would be greatly appreciated. pk

Comment: Please, please include more information about your setup. What language are you using? What HTML are you using?

Answer (score 0):

hi i think there is problem in your code. There is no issue with firefox browser and its version. You should check your code properly.